# Setting anchor for dynamic created controls

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I have winform on which are dynamically created 52 radio buttons.
This is method for creating them:

```
    private void CreateRadioButton()
    {            
        int rbCount = 52;
        int numberOfColumns = 23;

        radioButtons = new RadioButton[rbCount];
        int y = 520;

        for (int i = 0; i < rbCount; i++)
        {
            radioButtons[i] = new RadioButton();
            radioButtons[i].Text = Convert.ToString(i + 1);

            if (i % numberOfColumns == 0) 
                y += 20;

            var x = 11 + i % numberOfColumns * 50;

            radioButtons[i].Location = new Point(x, y);
            radioButtons[i].Size = new Size(40, 15);
            //radioButtons[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
            //radioButtons[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom;
            radioButtons[i].Font = new Font(radioButtons[i].Font.FontFamily, 8, FontStyle.Bold);
            radioButtons[i].UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            radioButtons[i].Click += new EventHandler(rbtns_click);

            xtraTab.Controls.Add(radioButtons[i]);            
        }          

    }
```

There is problem when form is maximized. Radio buttons disappear.
If I set

```
 radioButtons[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
 radioButtons[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom;
```

The radio buttons are overlayed.

What can I do to keep their position on the same place if form is resized?

Comment: [`[FlagsAttribute] public enum AnchorStyles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.anchorstyles(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

these two lines

```
radioButtons[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
radioButtons[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom;
```

mean that Anchor value `AnchorStyles.Left` will be replaced by `AnchorStyles.Bottom`

`AnchorStyles` has `Flags` attribute set, enum values can be combined:

```
radioButtons[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
```

if set via Designer, in "Windows Form Designer generated code" it looks like this:

```
this.radioButton1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)
   ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
```

Comment: @Josef, maybe starting `y` coordinate is too large (`int y = 520;`)? If parent  control (xtraTab) height is less that 520, all radio buttons will be outside its bounds and with anchor set to Bottom they will move down when parent is resized and still will be out of bounds. try change y to smaller value or try Anchor = Left | Top and resize

Comment: Now the radio buttons are not overlayed anymore but still after resizing form they disapera. Y position unfortunately must be 520 because the design requirement is to have radio buttons at bottom of all other controls.

Comment: here is what I get in a form 1024x768: [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vOee.png). some buttons on the right are not visible with this size, but became visible once I increase width or maximize. can you please share a screen with your problem

Comment: This is what i get [image](http://imgur.com/a/FHyrf) when I use  radioButtons[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Bottom
The same is for maximized or normal window size. Screen res. is 1920x1080, normal windows size is 1205; 820

Comment: @Josef, it looks to me as if there two sets of RadioButtons there (104 total)

Comment: You are right. I found mistake. Now everything works well. Another problem was in setting anchor. Now it is set to radioButtons[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Bottom; and works just I wanted. Thanks to all on effort and patience.